# Long column size in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = COMPANY_ID , length = 10)
private Long id;
```

[image]

in my sql it gets converted to BIGINT(20),what if i want it to be int(11) or how to give specific size to Long field??

Comment: You could try to define the table manually and then change the type and length if needed or just use `Integer` in your code. But why limit that in the first place? Storage isn't that expensive anymore.

Comment: From the JPA docs about Column(length): `Applies only if a string-valued column is used.`. There is no expectation for length to affect non-string types.

Answer (score 1):

you can use columnDefinition inside @Column()

```
 @Column(columnDefinition="BIGINT(20)")
```